ISSUE: Connection refused in the server running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connection- PgAdmin- Postgres
While registering a new server, and after using the
Host name/ Address :- localhost
port: 5432
its not letting me save it and this popup stops me to save and proceed.ISSUE: Connection refused in the server running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connection- PgAdmin- Postgres
I used the host name :- 127.0.0.1
and port:- 5433
restarted my system
re uninstalled and reinstalled PostgresQL and PgAdmin4.
